# Добавление в ListBoxItems циклом из массива

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Имеется массив с координатами точек, названием и содержимым для балуна, циклом добавляется в коллекцию и выводятся точки на карту. Но встал вопрос с добавлением названия точки в выпадающий список и по клике на списке переходу к координатам точки. Ну та вот, если описывать каждый элемент списка - все работает, но код громоздкий, пробовал записать ListBoxItems из массива - не получается.

Цикл добавления в коллекцию:

```js
for (var i = 0, l = myPoints.length; i < l; i++) {
        var point = myPoints[i];
        myCollection.add(new ymaps.Placemark(
            point.coords, {
   balloonContentHeader: point.textIcon,
            balloonContent: point.text,
   iconContent: point.id,
            iconCaption: point.textIcon
                
            }
        ));
    }
```

Работающее добавление в ListBoxItems:

```js
listBoxItems = [
      new ymaps.control.ListBoxItem({
                data: {
                    content: 'Школа 1',
                    center: [45.060930, 38.964569],
                    zoom: 14
                }
            }),
            new ymaps.control.ListBoxItem({
                data: {
                    content: 'Школа 2',
                    center: [45.035470, 38.975313],
                    zoom: 14
                }
            })
        ],
```

Не работающий цикл добавления в ListBoxItems:

```js
for (var i = 0, l = myPoints.length; i < l; i++) {
        var point = myPoints[i];
  new ymaps.control.ListBoxItem({
                data: {
                    content: point.id,
                    center: point.coords,
                    zoom: 14
                }
            });
  }
```

Сразу скажу что не особо шарю в программировании.

Answer (score 1):

Я это себе вижу примерно так

```js
ymaps.ready(init);

function init() {
    var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
            center: [55.76, 37.64],
            zoom: 10,
            controls: []
        }, {
            searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
        });

    var listBoxItems = [[60, 30], [61, 30], [62, 30], [63, 30], [64, 30], [65, 30]]
        .map(function(coords) {
            return new ymaps.control.ListBoxItem({
                data: {
                    content: 'Go to -> ' + coords,
                    coords: coords
                },
            options: {
                selectOnClick: false
            }
            })
        }),
        listBoxControl = new ymaps.control.ListBox({
            data: {
                content: 'Go to',
                title: 'Go to'
            },
            items: listBoxItems
        });
    myMap.controls.add(listBoxControl);

    listBoxControl.events.add(['click'], function(e) {
        var coords = e.get('target').data.get('coords');
        if(coords) {
            myMap.setCenter(coords);
        }
    });

}
```

```css
html, body, #map {
            width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 0; margin: 0;
        }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```